# Number of bit strings

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many bit strings of length 28

- Have at least one consecutive 000?
- Doesn't have consecutive 000's?

I'm using a TI-nspire calculator. Can I do it with the nCr function?

I tried to do it but I did not find a way.

Thank you.

I saw this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922659/number-of-binary-strings-of-length-8-that-contain-either-three-consecutive-0s-or) and [this one](http://www.techtud.com/doubt/combinatorics-how-many-bit-string-length-eight-contai), but they did not help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let **$a_n$** be a bit string of length *n* without 000, then it can be

**$a_{(n-3)}$** with 100 added at end,

or **$a_{(n-2)}$** with 10 added at end,

or **$a_{(n-1)}$** with 1 added at end.

So **$a_n = a_{(n-1)} +a_{(n-2)} + a_{(n-3)}$**

starting with  **$a_0 = 1, a_1=2, a_2 = 4$**

---

The ending of any successful chain can be categorised as **1**(111,101,011,001) **10**(110,010) or **100.**

**1** can be added to any successful chain of length **(n-1)** no matter what it ended with.

**10** can be added to any successful chain of length **(n-2)** no matter what it ended with.

**100** can be added to any successful chain of length **(n-3)** no matter what it ended with.

Comment: i'm beginning with discrete mathematics, could you give me a little bit more advice on what you wrote. Thank

Comment: Further explanation added.

Comment: thank you, i did a recurence and i found 29 249 425 without consecutive 000 and to have at least one consecutive 000 i have to do 2^28 - 29 249 425. Does it seams to be good?

Comment: You're welcome ! Look up Tribonacci numbers on OEIS to check your figures.

Comment: Thank :) and could you explain me how did you find a0 =1 a1=1 a2=4

Comment: In recurrence relations, you may need a few starting values. a1, by the way, was given as 2 [1 and 0] similarly, a2 is 4 [00,01,10,11] You should be able to check that a0+a1+a2 = 7 is correct for a 3 bit string (all but 000 are successful chains)